# One hot encoding of target space

Tags: data-cleaning, preprocessing, classifier

I had a face to face interview for a data scientist job a few days ago. One of the questions I was asked was: in the case of classifier predicting the brand of TV from some features (price, size, specs, ...) out of 4 possible brands, how do you encode the brand variable? My answer was `one hot encoding`, it was accepted but then they asked me to do it explicitly and I sketched something like:

```
brand A -> [1,0,0,0]
brand B -> [0,1,0,0]
brand C -> [0,0,1,0]
brand D -> [0,0,0,1]
```

And then, I was corrected under the reason that these columns were not independent. And that the solution should have been three binary columns instead.

Later it hit me that I do not know why independence is required, and also that three binary variables are not independent. Two would be.

Can someone provide some explanation to help with my confusion?

Comment: Either you or your interviewer mixed up the things. If it is one hot encoding, then your answer is perfect but if they told you that three binary columns would have done the job, then they are talking about Binary labels, not one hot encoding. With three binary labels, you can actually represent four categories as `001, 010, 011, 100 `

Comment: you only need two features to represent four categorical levels: 00, 01, 10, 11. Three dimensions could encode up to 8 factor levels. But this is not an appropriate way to distinguish four classes in the target of a multiclass classification, and it is not necessarily a great approach for input encoding either.

Answer (score 1):

For certain models, it can be important to make sure the inputs are linearly independent. I'm pretty sure this is never the case for the outputs. If we have more than two classes, it's extremely difficult if not impossible to output class-probabilities if we don't have a specific dimension for each class in the output vector. In other words, your suggestion has much more explanatory power than what was suggested by your interviewer, which is solving a problem that exists on the inputs for some models but not for the outputs.

In multi-class problems, it is indeed the norm that each class has their own dimension in the output vector as you suggested. Either the interviewer was trying to look smart and confused input and output encoding (which still would only apply to certain families of models), or you aren't remembering the events of the interview properly. If you're confident that the interview went as you described, you should consider complaining to your point of contact that you were criticized for giving a correct answer.

Feel free to cite the following as popular/canonical examples of multi-class classifiers:

- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba

> Returns: array of shape = [n_samples, n_classes]

- https://keras.io/losses/#categorical_crossentropy

> when using the categorical_crossentropy loss, your targets should be in categorical format (e.g. if you have 10 classes, the target for each sample should be a 10-dimensional vector that is all-zeros expect for a 1 at the index corresponding to the class of the sample)